# React useState to update a specific item in its array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of images inside `refData`. I then map them into an array of img objects with `RefItem`. I then want thouse specifc images to change to the next one in a line - so img 0 becomes 1, and 1 becomes 2 - as written in `refbox`. I just cannot figure this one out.. I just want to update the individual numbers in each array item?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import refData from './refData'
import RefItem from './refItem'

function ReferencesPP(){
    const refItems = refData.map(item => <RefItem key={item.id} pitem={item}/>)

    const [refs, setRefs] = useState([0, 1, 2, 3])

    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setTimeout(() => {
            for(let i = 0; i < refs.length; i++){
                if(refs[i] !== refData.length){
                    setRefs(...refs[i], refs[i] = refs[i] + 1)
                } else {
                    setRefs(...refs[i], refs[i] = 0)
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
        return () => clearTimeout(intervalId);
    }, [refs]);

    return(
        <div className="referencespp-container">
            <div className="background-container" />
            <div className="content-container">
                <div id="refbox"> 
                    {refItems[refs[0]]}
                    {refItems[refs[1]]}
                    {refItems[refs[2]]}
                    {refItems[refs[3]]}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ReferencesPP
```

I thought it would be as simple, as writing

```
const refs = [0, 1, 2, 3]
useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        for(let i = 0; i < refs.length; i++){
            if(refs[i] !== refData.length){
                refs[i] = refs[i] + 1;
            } else {
                refs[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, []);
```

but doing that only updates the `const` and not the `{refItems[refs[0]]}` elements?

Comment: I think using `shift` and `push` might be a better idea

Comment: but how do i update a specific item in the array using push then? Say i want to update `refs[2]` to be `refs[2] = refs[2] + 1` ?

Comment: I thought you just wanted to update all of them - remove the first and add it to the end, so 0 becomes 1 and so on

Comment: I do want to update all of them to be one number higher until the number is as high as `refData.length`, then i want it to return to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/gwbo4pdu/ I think it's what you want to get

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setTimeout(() => {
       const newRefs = [...refs]
       const i = newRefs.shift()
       newRefs.push(i)
       setRefs(newRefs);
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearTimeout(intervalId);
}, [refs]);
```

P.S. you can do just `newRefs.push(newRefs.shift())`